# How modern is the current paradigm of parenting?

Tags: family, children, parenting

Currently there is a parenting paradigm of emotionally involved, caring, loving parent-child relationships. This can be reflected in activities like reading to children, spending time in the park, playing with them, singing to them, buying toys and clothe to them, etc.

How modern is this paradigm of parenting? Has research shown some general conclusion about whether the current paradigm is "modern"? (e.g. fostered by the same forces that gave rise to the human rights, officially stamped by the UN in 1948, and the more direct children human rights, stamped by the UN in 1959). I am aware of anecdotal evidence of some upper classes (including nobility and royalty, particularly female) fostering loving parent-child relationships (mostly through literature and history). More broadly, I found [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1081975/?page=2) of a 1976 book on the topic covering "western culture" from Roman times to XIX century, concluding that

> the picture revealed here is one of unloving handling of children in the past, when abuse of them far exceeded devoted care.

I have no idea if this +45 years old image still holds (review called this an under-researched area). It would be interesting to know of other cultures and specific historical settings (e.g. ancient Asian cultures, classical antiquity, medieval ages, Mayan empire, tribal societies, ...). Still, anything that helps gets an idea of modern view of the question is welcome.

Comment: I suspect that all parents would describe themselves as "good"; a friend of mine was abandoned by her parents as a child without notice - but they still perceive themselves as good parents.  Historically "good" parents believed that sparing the rod would spoil the child. How are you going to define the paradigm and test for "goodness"? You've provided a reference for the definition of "modern", but I'm not sure that it is clear enough for me to apply to any other situation.  Is the automobile not modern because it predates 1948?  Relativity is not modern? Votes for women is not modern?

Comment: The number of stories of parents going to extreme ends to help/promote their children, sometimes to the [detriment of their country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodus) would seem to indicate that there have always been strong parent/child bonds.

Comment: The telling by [Hiram Percy Maxim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiram_Percy_Maxim) (no, not [THAT Maxim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiram_Maxim) - his son) of ["*A Scientific Whipping*"](https://soundcloud.com/reading-aloud-1/a-genius-in-the-family-chapter-6-a-scientific-whipping) at the hands of his father in about 1875 tells much about parenting in Victorian England. It's a 10 minute listen, and was a favourite story of my own from about age 8, when I first encountered it in **A Reader's Digest treaury for Young Readers**.

Comment: I might look into it if I can grab a few minutes in the next few days, but my SWAG would be that this is tied in with the general view that one parent should stay home and take care of the house and children as their full-time job, which I believe goes back only to the 19th Century. One would imagine the importance of the children in that equation likely increased as the amount of the day consumed by cooking, washing, and cleaning decreased.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Mmm, I see the use of the "good" adjective is not appropriate since the conception of what is "good" changes too (no one would have liked to be perceived, let alone self-perceived as being a bad parent). Updated the question.

Comment: This is a good question but the modern, nurturing paradigm of parenting is hard to pin down. Maybe pick a few aspects (corporeal punishment, is the child a person in themself or just prospective adult, emotional onvolvement) and how they are treated in literature aimed at parents.

Comment: It's complex because while in some way parents are more hands-on (spending quality time with children now being a goal), in other ways, with the growth in working women (at least in higher social classes), especially women doing full-time demanding jobs, and changing work/commuting patterns it's going to be hard to generalise even about basic things like the amount of contact children have with their parents. Maybe you could restrict it by social class and geographical area.

Comment: Note that while noble families were packing junior off to the neighbors for diplomatic reasons, in peasant families, junior was probably working the fields with mom and dad at eight years old.  Nearly all history is about that small minority (nobles) as opposed to the bulk of humanity (peasants)